# STM32F407 ADC with timer trigger not working for some reason

Tags: stm32, adc, embedded, timer

For STM32F407 discovery board, I tried to establish ADC for measuring voltage at a point, using timer to trigger the ADC, every clock cycle.
Somehow I have missed something, because the timer clock is not able to trigger the ADC, rather it is working only once, due to init function. What have I missed?

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"


unsigned int value;
float stepSize=0.01171;
float voltage;
int x=0;
void TIM2_Configuration(void){
    // enable TIM2 clock (bit0)
    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1 << 0);


        TIM2->PSC = 16000-1;
    TIM2->ARR = 1000; //

     /* Reset the MMS Bits */
  TIM2->CR2 &= (uint16_t)~TIM_CR2_MMS;
  /* Select the TRGO source */
  TIM2->CR2 |=  TIM_CR2_MMS_1; //UPDATE EVENT



    // Update Interrupt Enable
    TIM2->DIER |= (1 << 0);

    // enable TIM2 IRQ from NVIC
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

    // Enable Timer 2 module (CEN, bit0)
    TIM2->CR1 |= (1 << 0);


}

void init_ADC(void)
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR|=RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;  //GPIOC clock enable
    GPIOC->MODER|=(3u<<(2*0));  //ADC input pin is analog mode, PC0
    RCC->APB2ENR|=RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN;       //ADC clock enable
    ADC1->SQR1&=~ADC_SQR1_L;                        //set number of conversions per sequence to 1
    ADC1->SQR3&=~ADC_SQR3_SQ1;                  //clear channel select bits
    ADC1->SQR3|=10;                     //set channel
    ADC1->CR1 &= ~ADC_CR1_SCAN; //SCAN mode disabled
    ADC1->CR2 &= ~ADC_CR2_CONT; //disable continuous conversion

    ADC1->CR2 &=  ~(1<<29);
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<28);   //Trigger on Rising edge

    //External Event TIM2 TRGO
    ADC1->CR2 |= 0x14<<24;


    ADC1->SMPR2 |= 7<<0; //488 cycles



    ADC1->CR2|=ADC_CR2_ADON;                        //enable ADC
    ADC1->CR2|=ADC_CR2_SWSTART;
}

void msDelay(int msTime)
{
//Assume for loop take 12 clock cycles and system clock is 16MHz
int Time=msTime*1333;
    for(int i=0;i<Time;i++);

}

int main(){
    //FPU enable
    //Co-processor (core peripheral) access control register
    SCB->CPACR|=(0xF<<20);
    TIM2_Configuration();
    init_ADC();
    msDelay(500);
    x++;
    while(1)
        {

        while (!(ADC1->SR & (1<<1))){

                    __NOP();

                }

                    value = ADC1->DR;
                    voltage = stepSize*value;
                    ADC1->SR = 0;
    }
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{


    // clear interrupt status
    if (TIM2->DIER & 0x01) {
        if (TIM2->SR & 0x01) {
            TIM2->SR &= ~(1U << 0);
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //External Event TIM2 TRGO
>     ADC1->CR2 |= 0x14<<24;
> ```

According to ADC_CR2 description in RM0090, EXTSEL field has only 4 bits, thus 0x14 writes also to EXTEN field. For TIM2 TRGO to be source of trigger, you need to write 0b0110 = 0x6 into ADC_CR2.EXTSEL.

Comment: Whoa, thanks a lot! I'd actually confused 6 with 14, in hexadecimal. Since 6 is 0110, and 14 is 1110. 
Anyways thanks!